# Access Burst Mode photos in library

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset, alassetsgroup

I’m trying to access photos in the iOS asset library that the user has taken using Burst Mode. I’m trying using `ALAssetsLibrary` and filtering photos:

```
- (void)findBurstModePhotos
{
    ALAssetsFilter *allPhotos = [ALAssetsFilter allPhotos];

    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                                usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group,
                                             BOOL *stop) {
                                    [group setAssetsFilter:allPhotos];

                                    NSLog(@"Group: %@",
                                          [group valueForProperty:
                                           ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]);

                                    if ([group numberOfAssets] > 0) {
                                        [self evaluateGroup:group];
                                    }
                                }
                              failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"Failure enumerating groups: %@",
                                        [error localizedDescription]);
                              }];
}

- (void)evaluateGroup:(ALAssetsGroup *)group
{
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result,
                                       NSUInteger index,
                                       BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Photo date: %@", [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]);
    }];
}
```

Unfortunately, this returns Burst Mode photos as a single photo. Is there a supported way to get Burst Mode photos individually? I’d like to get each photo from a single Burst Mode session.

Comment: You might have already verified this but I hope you have not deleted all other versions of photos except the favorite one in burst mode.

Comment: Good guess, but I have not deleted the other versions of the photo.

Comment: This is more of a question than anything - but when you inspect the *result's property `ALAssetPropertyType` is it reporting as `ALAssetTypePhoto`? I ask because I wonder if there's a new ALAssetType that they just don't have documented yet (in the unexpected case that the API to utilize these types has not fully been implemented yet).

Comment: Yep, all photos. I tried removing the `ALAssetsFilter` and looking for all types, but no luck.

Comment: Is it just an 5 / 5S difference that I don't get the chance to save just one? It seems I get all photos as separate photos.

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of `ALAssetPropertyURLs` for the available burst favourite?

Comment: @JamesWebster: It looks like you’re right. It’s the 5/5s difference.

Comment: @Wain: I tried looking at the value for `ALAssetPropertyURLs`, but it returns one URL for Burst Mode photos taken on an iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 1):

From my understandings, the Burst Mode photos will be added to the library as one by one.The `ALAssetProperty` type of each image will be `ALAssetTypePhoto`.So you can get each photo separately using the below ALAsset block. You can't retrieve only the set of Burst Mode photos at a time because there are only 7 types of `ALAssetsGroupTypes` and 3 kinds of `ALAssetsFilters` are available. None of them are dealing with Burst Mode photos.

I hope Apple will provide Burst photo filtering in the future.

```
---------------------------- ALAssetsGroupType -------------------------------------------

ALAssetsGroupLibrary      // The Library group that includes all assets.
ALAssetsGroupAlbum        // All the albums synced from iTunes or created on the device.
ALAssetsGroupEvent        // All the events synced from iTunes.
ALAssetsGroupFaces        // All the faces albums synced from iTunes.
ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos  // The Saved Photos album.
ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream  // The PhotoStream album.
ALAssetsGroupAll          // The same as ORing together all the available group types,with the exception that ALAssetsGroupLibrary is not included.


-------------------------- ALAssetsFilter ------------------------------------------------

+ (ALAssetsFilter *)allPhotos; // Get all photos assets in the assets group.
+ (ALAssetsFilter *)allVideos; // Get all video assets in the assets group.
+ (ALAssetsFilter *)allAssets; // Get all assets in the group.
```

Use the below code to get each photo separately including the Burst Mode photos,

```
- (void)findBurstModePhotos
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [ViewController defaultAssetsLibrary];

    [assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

      if(result)
      {
        [self evaluateGroup:group];
      }

    }];

    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading images %@", error);
    }];
}

- (void)evaluateGroup:(ALAssetsGroup *)group
{
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result,
                                       NSUInteger index,
                                       BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"Photo date: %@", [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate]);
    }];
}

+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library;
}
```

**Output Log:**

```
Photo date: 2013-05-06 15:57:21 +0000 //non burst image.
Photo date: 2013-05-06 15:57:41 +0000 //non burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:40 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:41 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:41 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:41 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:41 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:42 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:42 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:42 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:43 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:43 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:43 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:44 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:44 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:44 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:44 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:45 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:45 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:45 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:45 +0000 //burst image.
Photo date: 2013-12-20 21:10:46 +0000 //burst image.
```

**Note:**

If the Burst Mode photo capture camera is a part of your application,then store the `ALAsset URL's` when saving the captured photos to the photo gallery.You can retrieve this photo back using the saved `ALAsset URL's` via `ALAsset` library.

Comment: What device were you using when you took those photos? Using similar code I’m only getting one photo back on an iPhone 5s.

Comment: did you save all the pics into photo-gallery? using any 3rd party app to capture it? or using the default camera?

Comment: Also your code is little differ than mine.Update your code as mine , check the results and get back to me. Also I hope that you can see all the Burst mode pics in your device photos gallery.Please confirm.

Comment: This is essentially the same as my answer but with a less complete solution.

Comment: From my testing, it looks like iPhone 5s devices do a different Burst Mode, so that explains the difference in our results. Thanks for your help, but the above code will not work on a 5s.

Comment: @Ramshad So your solution is basically to check timestamps to see if the images were taken closely together? If that's all we have - then I really do hope apple does something about this in the near future.

Comment: @AndrewPK: Yeah.that's all we have presently:)